# Event handler not working on dynamic content even with event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mouseenter, dynamic-html

I have two ModalPopups
The first one opens and has a Tooltip text that the user can view for more detail with the "mouseenter" event listener.
Once the user clicks to close the modal through one of three buttons, the second ModalPopup opens with another Tooltip text. The Tooltip text on "mouseenter" does not work in this second ModalPopup.
This is an entirely new Modalpopup although I have tried using the same modal and it still doesn't work.

So the flow is:
User clicks button -> loading -> ModalPopup with tooltip -> User clicks 1 button out of 3 options -> Modalpopup closes -> loading -> ModalPopup number 2 with tooltip -> etc...

So it's loading dynamic content, then using delegation to set the tooltip listeners, then closing/deleting that content, then loading more dynamic content afterwards, and trying to again use delegated tooltip listeners for the second time.

I've tried removing the tooltip altogether on each modal load, unbinding everything on modal load before rebinding, unbinding in the tooltip code before rebinding, and etc.

Interestingly, when the second modalpopup opens, if I "Inspect Element" using chrome, the tooltips start working again.

Tootip Code:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $.fn.extend({
        jqToolTip: function () {
            var opts = {
                tooltipDiv: 'tooltipbox',
                tooltipFadeOut: 'tooltipFadeOut',
                tooltipBoxTop: 'tooltipbox-top',
                tooltipBoxRight: 'tooltipbox-right',
                tooltipBoxLeft: 'tooltipbox-left',
                tooltipBoxBottom: 'tooltipbox-bottom',
                tooltipBoxRed: 'tooltipbox-red',
                tooltipBoxBottomRed: 'tooltipbox-bottom-red',
                tooltipBoxTopRed: 'tooltipbox-top-red',
                tooltipBoxLeftRed: 'tooltipbox-left-red',
                tooltipBoxRightRed: 'tooltipbox-right-red'
            };
            const classSelector = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/).find(x => x.includes("tooltip"));

            $(document.body).live('mouseenter', `.${classSelector}`, function (e) {
                var color = $(this).data("tooltip-color");
                var arrowOffsetx = $(this).data("tooltip-arrow-offset-x");
                var arrowOffsety = $(this).data("tooltip-arrow-offset-y");
                var helptext = $(this).data("tooltip");
                var direction = $(this).data("tooltip-direction");
                if (direction == null) direction = 'right';
                var top = $(this).offset().top;
                var left = $(this).offset().left;
                var offsetX = $(this).data("tooltip-offset-x");
                if (offsetX == null) offsetX = 0;
                var offsetY = $(this).data("tooltip-offset-y");
                if (offsetY == null) offsetY = 0;
                //console.log(top,left,$(this).width());
                var cssAdd = '';
                var cssColorAdd = '';
                $('.' + opts.tooltipDiv).removeClass(opts.tooltipFadeOut + ' '
                    + opts.tooltipBoxBottom + ' '
                    + opts.tooltipBoxRight + ' '
                    + opts.tooltipBoxTop + ' '
                    + opts.tooltipBoxLeft + ' '
                    + opts.tooltipBoxRed + ' '
                    + opts.tooltipBoxBottomRed + ' '
                    + opts.tooltipBoxTopRed + ' '
                    + opts.tooltipBoxLeftRed + ' '
                    + opts.tooltipBoxRightRed).html(helptext);
                switch (direction) {
                    case 'top': // top
                        top = top - 48 + offsetY;
                        left = left + $(this).width() / 2 - 25 + offsetX;
                        cssAdd = opts.tooltipBoxTop;
                        cssColorAdd = opts.tooltipBoxTopRed;
                        break;
                    case 'right': // right
                        top = top + $(this).height() / 2 - 13 + offsetY;
                        left = left + $(this).width() + 20 + offsetX;
                        cssAdd = opts.tooltipBoxRight;
                        cssColorAdd = opts.tooltipBoxRightRed;
                        break;
                    case 'bottom': // bottom
                        top = top + $(this).height() + 14 + offsetY;
                        left = left + $(this).width() / 2 - 28 + offsetX;
                        cssAdd = opts.tooltipBoxBottom;
                        cssColorAdd = opts.tooltipBoxBottomRed;
                        break;
                    case 'left': // left
                        top = top + $(this).height() / 2 - 13 + offsetY;
                        left = left - $('.' + opts.tooltipDiv).width() - 16 + offsetX;
                        cssAdd = opts.tooltipBoxLeft;
                        cssColorAdd = opts.tooltipBoxLeftRed;
                        break;
                }
                //console.log(left);
                if (color == 'red') {
                    $('.' + opts.tooltipDiv).addClass(opts.tooltipBoxRed);
                    $('.' + opts.tooltipDiv).addClass(cssColorAdd);
                }
                if (typeof(arrowOffsetx) != "undefined" && arrowOffsetx.length > 0) {
                    $('.' + opts.tooltipDiv)
                        .addClass('tooltipBoxArrowOffsetX')
                        .append('<style>.tooltipBoxArrowOffsetX::after,.tooltipBoxArrowOffsetX::before{left:' + arrowOffsetx + ' !important;}</style>')
                }
                if (typeof (arrowOffsety) != "undefined" && arrowOffsety.length > 0) {
                    $('.' + opts.tooltipDiv)
                        .addClass('tooltipBoxArrowOffsetY')
                        .append('<style>.tooltipBoxArrowOffsetY::after,.tooltipBoxArrowOffsetY::before{left:' + arrowOffsety + ' !important;}</style>');
                }
                $('.' + opts.tooltipDiv).addClass(cssAdd).css({ left: left, top: top }).fadeIn();
            })
            $(document.body).live('mouseleave', `.${classSelector}`, function (e) {
                $('.' + opts.tooltipDiv).addClass(opts.tooltipFadeOut);
            })
            $(document.body).live('click', `.${classSelector}`, function (e) {
                var ishide = $(this).data("tooltip-onclickhide") == '1';
                if (ishide) $('.' + opts.tooltipDiv).addClass(opts.tooltipFadeOut);
            })

            return this;
        },
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event delegation for "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events can only be done in the capturing phase.

Replace

```js
$(document.body).live('mouseenter', `.${classSelector}`, function (e){}
```

with

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    if (e.target.matches(`.${classSelector}`)) {
        // code here
        // use e.target instead of this
    }
}, true);
```

The same applies for "mouseleave".

Comment: This didn't work. Thanks though for the answer. It seems like when my Modal closes, it doesn't fire any sortof mouse leave event. So when the next modal opens, the mouse is already "over" the content. So it never fires the mouseenter event. When I open the inspect window, it finally fires a mouseleave event and allows the tooltips to work.

Comment: @Aquaphor Perhaps try `document` instead of `document.body` for attaching the event listener.

Comment: Your original answer did end up working. My issue was that I didn't properly destroy the JSTooltip after the first modal closed. Which was leaving a blank invisible tooltip overtop the hover text. So it wasn't detecting my mouse. But your original answer did fix my original problem :)